# Can't log into WordPress after domain change

Tags: wp-admin, login, errors

I can not reach my dasboard when I try

```
www.mydomain.com/wp-admin
```

it redirect and becomes

```
...wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1"
```

this and I can not reach the log in I have tried a lot of things still the same. That happened because I changed my wordpress url and web site url to http to https I have solved it sort of from my database options table and then this happened.

Comment: review this codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: Do not use multiple accounts. You should create one and stick with it. See [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

Well I did solve this. I have downgraded the wordpress version. I uploaded the old wp files to my server. Files should be rewritten ones in the server. Then I go back to website and upgrade it. Problem solved! This is my solution no other sugessions have worked for me.

And the last warning DO NOT CHANGE YOUR WEBSITE URL EVER!!!! :)